# Is there a way to quickly add a class to a pre-existing element in VSCode? (with Emmet Notation)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, emmet

When you want to create a div with a class already applied, you can just type `div.foo` and VSCode will change it to be `<div class="foo"></div>`, but what if you want to add a class or id to an already existing element?

E.g you already have a div `<div></div>`, but you want to add a class called `bar` to it, to make it `<div class="bar"></div>`

Is there any way you can do this with Emmet notation, VSCode, or some other extension?

Comment: set the cursor after the `div` and type `SPACEclTAB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I've come up with is after <div add a space and then type cl "tab" classname.